# SSD not appearing in UEFI after reinstalling

Tags: boot

I have an Asus N550-JV laptop. I had added a SSD instead of the optical drive. Then the screen stopped working so I had to send it into reparation. Before doing so though I removed the SSD and put back the optical drive, this way I figured whatever they do I will be able to put my SSD back in and boot from there. It wasn't a bad idea as it looks like they restored my laptop to factory settings, with a clean Windows 8 installation. But after having reinstalled my SSD, it looks like I cannot boot on it. It looks like the UEFI doesn't consider it a bootable device. What can I do?

Comment: Enable legacy mode and install the OS in BIOS-compatibility mode.

Comment: I don't know what that means :> Enable legacy mode on what? The disk is seen I can access it and everything but it isn't seen as a bootable device

Comment: @Nico - Legacy or CSM or Compatability Mode.  Overmind is suggesting you disable UEFI mode and use MBR instead of GPT.

Comment: Legacy mode on boot process, yes. You can't practically disable UEFI, but you can enable the boot process to work in the classical way. All problems gone.

Comment: Insert some more information in question - what style is SSD, MBR or UEFI,  what style is hard disk - the easiest would be to copy output of diskpart, list disk command.